# Fancybox 3 content focus jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, fancybox-3

I im currently upgrading Fancybox 2 to Fancybox 3, in one of my FB 3 overlays (inline) i have a form with a input field with a jquery UI datepicker. In FB2 when you open the picker you can click outside the picker and within the form to close it, but with FB3 clicking outside the datepicker within the form (like on the labels) the focus is not set anymore and the picker will not close. Only way to close the picker is with right-mouse or to select an other input field. How can i fix this? it has something to do with the "clickContent : function( current, event ) {}" that is used in FancyBox 3.

device is desktop, on mobile/tablet it works ok.

Comment: Have you tried disabling touch events using `touch:false` option?

Comment: yes i tried, you can mark/select the label text with touch:false, but the picker is not closed. When i select an other input field when the picker is open the picker will close, that works fine. Problem is that the picker hides other input fields when opened.

Comment: Have you tried setting `autoFocus` and `trapFocus` to false?

Comment: Yes i have, with no effect

Comment: Then the only solution I can think of would be to close datepicker manually using from within `clickContent`method that you can pass as an option.

Comment: i will look if i can set the focus myself in the FB3 code. Or if more problems like this will occure i stick with FB2. The helper functionality is also missing that i used to lock the background content for scrolling on tablet and mobile. Closing all possible UI implementations (i use a timepicker somewhere to) is not a decent solution. FB3 should not cause this behavior especially when FB2 worked like a charm.